# Connection refused while connecting to a docker image deployed on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, fluentd

I deployed a docker image running a fluentd instance on Elastic Beanstalk

I want to send messages to fluentd from another Elastic Beanstalk application, but I receive *java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused*.

in fluend.conf I set

```
<source>
  type forward
  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 24224
</source>
```

In Dockerfile i set

```
EXPOSE 24224
```

In Dockerrun.aws.json

```
"Ports": [
 {
   "ContainerPort": "24224"
 }
]
```

The fluentd node can be pinged from the client node, but it seems that the  port 24224 is not exposed correctly to the rest of the environment.

Running the fluentD docker container locally, it works.

Where can I look to solve my problem?

Comment: Is your port 24224 open in security group you are using?

Comment: yes, for both tcp and udp protocols

Comment: While connecting to the node via ssh, I cannot connect with telnet to localhost:24224, but i can connect to "virtual docker machine":24224. So it seems that the reverse proxy is not working...